# Route some clients through router openvpn client file

Tags: openvpn

I have added a openvpn client to my router. This works but all my devices are using the vpn.

I want some devices to use the vpn and others not to.

To illustrate

A (phone) => no vpn regular traffic

B (TV) => vpn traffic

C (computer) => no vpn regular traffic

Can this be achived with only the openvpn file config? I can't use software for devices to configure vpn settings.

(I dont have access to the server config file)

Comment: What exactly is the router (hardware) and what is the system (software) on it, besides OpenVPN?

Answer (score -1):

If using linux, one way to achieve this is by using network spaces. Look at the [wireguard official doc](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/).

It's not newbie-friendly though.

Comment: Sorry, please, elaborate your answer. I work with Linux for 20+ years, and did not understand what "not newbie-friendly" way of using namespaces and wireguard you are talking about, when the question was about router and openvpn.

Comment: I said one way, and didn't say ONLY way.

Sometimes you don't have to take the terminologies at face value. People (including me) sometime phrase questions differently to what they actually want.

Back to the query. He can: 1) configure netns on the router on a separate vlan. 2) Or, just moved the tv onto its own subnet where vpn is configured.

No need to mention your 20+ linux years. I have already 40+ years with linux, yet i'm only 35 :)